# SQL Exception: the index is out of range

Tags: java, jdbc

When I run my program, it show the error the column is out of range. Connection is ok

For exmaple

```
updateRecoredtoStudent(15, "Annies","Bot"," Ionia", "1/1/2013","firstname","Anny")
```

```
 private static void updateRecordToStudent(int studentid, String firstname, String lastname,String address, String dateofbirth, String cond_col, String cond_val) throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE student SET 'studentid' = ? 'firstname' = ? 'lastname' = ? 'address' = ? dateofbirth' = ? WHERE ? = ?";
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

                    preparedStatement.setInt(1, studentid); 
        preparedStatement.setString(2, firstname); 
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, lastname);
                    preparedStatement.setString(4, address); 
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, dateofbirth);
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, cond_col);
                    preparedStatement.setString(7, cond_val);


        // execute update SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Record is updated to STUDENT table!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}
```

```
 Student table contains
-studentid(int-PK)
-Firstname(String)
-lastname(String)
-Address(String)
-Dateofbirth(String)
```

Comment: You have typos (missing quotes). You also have wrong indices (multiple times 5)

Comment: You can not have column names as a parameter in a prepared statement - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008336/having-a-column-name-as-input-parameter-of-a-preparedstatement

Comment: `SET 'studentid' = ?` is invalid SQL. Column names need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes (or no quotes at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wrong code statement. Please try the following.

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE student SET 'studentid' = ? 'firstname' = ? 'lastname' = ? 'address' = ? dateofbirth' = ?  WHERE " + cond_col + "= ?";
try {
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

    preparedStatement.setInt(1, studentid); 
    preparedStatement.setString(2, firstname); 
    preparedStatement.setString(3, lastname);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, address); 
    preparedStatement.setString(5, dateofbirth);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, cond_val);
```

Comment: I chek that but all input is correct with correspoding limiit in table

Comment: I think the wrong thing in the sql query, maybe in preparedstatement

Answer (score 1):

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE student SET studentid = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, address = ?, dateofbirth = ? WHERE "+cond_col+" = ?";
preparedStatement.setInt(1, studentid); 
preparedStatement.setString(2, firstname); 
preparedStatement.setString(3, lastname);
preparedStatement.setString(4, address); 
preparedStatement.setString(5, dateofbirth);
preparedStatement.setString(6, cond_val);
```

Only column values can be set. If you want to pass dynamic column name you should concat it with query. One more thing missing `,` between column name.

Comment: You also need to remove the `'`s around column names.  Otherwise you're trying to assign values to strings, which won't work.

Comment: Ok I will try it .Thanks for yor help

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL syntax to be like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

So your SQL UPDATE query will be:

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE student SET studentid=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, address=?, dateofbirth=? WHERE " + fieldName + " = ?";
```