# avg() with sqlite-jdbc

Tags: sqlitejdbc

I have a query which relies on avg() using sqlite-jdbc to connect to a sqlite database. However when my query runs I get an answer of 0.0 for the average, but when I run the same query elsewhere (portable database viewer) I get the expected (non-zero) value. Why?

Column being averaged is a list of integers.

```
SELECT COUNT(col) as count, AVG(col) as average FROM table WHERE <many-clauses-here>
```

The count returns correctly.

Values being averaged:
    "54", "56", "66", "53"

The file format is sqlite, but the way it is styled is in the spec given by [ddf spec](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVQG_6.0.1/com.spss.ddl/dimensions_file_dsc_schema.htm?lang=en) though this should not be relevant

Comment: Can you show us the query and the data involved?  There could be a rounding issue at work here.

Comment: That is something I would have never thought of. This is for work so I will check tomorrow against other sets of values as well.

Comment: Probably a different database.

Comment: A second set of values also produces 0.0 while the database viewer produces a non-zero value. Could sqlitejdbc be misinterpreting type and thinking they're strings when they're actually longs?

Answer (score 0):

After I tried using a regular statement instead of a PreparedStatement, I found it worked as intended. I was using JDBC incorrectly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008336/having-a-column-name-as-input-parameter-of-a-preparedstatement) - I'm newish to JDBC (haven't used it in ages)  so I made a rookie mistake, but it manifested itself so oddly.